# Casting Windows.Controls.UserControl to Windows.Forms.Control

Tags: c#, wpf

Can we cast a WPF User Control to a form control??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this out:

```
TouchScreenWPF touchUI = new TouchScreenWPF();
ElementHost elementHost = new ElementHost();
elementHost.Child = touchUI;
Control userControl = new Control();
userControl.Controls.Add(elementHost);
```

The form contains the usercontrol, but does not display anything when I include a WPF User control. It works with a single button though... Am I missing something there?

Comment: I got the answer.  I had to put a height and a width with the element host and the usercontrol!!  Thanks CHEERS!! WPF!!

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry you can't. WPF works very differently internally from Winforms: Winforms uses the controls provided by the Windows OS (where each control has a window handle), where WPF uses DirectX to do the painting.

You can host WPF controls inside winforms applications (EDIT)**and vice versa** (with limitations) but that is perhaps not what you're after.

Comment: you can however host a WPF Control in a WinForm app using the ElementHost control ; if that is what you're trying to do http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx

Comment: @Gishu: yeah, it works in both directions. Was going to mention that but got distracted.

Comment: Thanks for the ElementHost.  That is exactly what I needed.  I have another problem though.  With a WPF Button it works fine, but when I want to display a WPF User Control, it appears blank on the form.  Do you what can be the reason?